# jquery length scale identifier

Tags: jquery

```
![scale image][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUjSU.png


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#gettext').bind('input',function(){ 
        $('.deadline1 > li').css('background-color','transparent');
        var valuesX = $('#gettext').val();
        $('#ap_feet').val(valuesX);
        $('.deadline1 li').each(function(){
            var strip =  $(this).attr('data');
            if(strip == valuesX)
            {
               for(var i=4; i<=strip; i++)
               { 
                   $('#neck_'+i).css('background-color','red');
                   $('div[id^="'+i+'."]').filter(function(){return this.id.match(/\d+$/)}).css('background-color','red');
                   console.log(i);
               }
            }
        });
    });

    });

</script>

<ul class="deadline1">
    <li id="neck_7" data="7"><span class="feet_num">7 feet</span> ____</li>
    <li id="neck_6.11" data="6.11">.</li>
    <li id="neck_6.10" data="6.10">.</li>
    <li id="neck_6.9" data="6.9">.</li>
    <li id="neck_6.8" data="6.8">.</li>
    <li id="neck_6.7" data="6.7">.</li>
    <li id="neck_6.6" data="6.6">__</li>
    <li id="neck_6.5" data="6.5">.</li>
    <li id="neck_6.4" data="6.4">.</li>
    <li id="neck_6.3" data="6.3">.</li>
    <li id="neck_6.2" data="6.2">.</li>
    <li id="neck_6.1" data="6.1">.</li>
    <li id="neck_6" data="6"><span class="feet_num">6 feet</span> ____</li>
    <li id="neck_5.11" data="5.11">.</li>
    <li id="neck_5.10" data="5.10">.</li>
    <li id="neck_5.8" data="5.9">.</li>
    <li id="neck_5.8" data="5.8">.</li>
    <li id="neck_5.7" data="5.7">.</li>
    <li id="neck_5.6" data="5.6">__</li>
    <li id="neck_5.5" data="5.5">.</li>
    <li id="neck_5.4" data="5.4">.</li>
    <li id="neck_5.3" data="5.3">.</li>
    <li id="neck_5.2" data="5.2">.</li>
    <li id="neck_5.1" data="5.1">.</li>
    <li id="neck_5" data="5"><span class="feet_num">5 feet</span>____</li>
    <li id="neck_4.11" data="4.11">.</li>
    <li id="neck_4.10" data="4.10">.</li>
    <li id="neck_4.9" data="4.9">.</li>
    <li id="neck_4.8" data="4.8">.</li>
    <li id="neck_4.7" data="4.7">.</li>
    <li id="neck_4.6" data="4.6">__</li>
    <li id="neck_4.5" data="4.5">.</li>
    <li id="neck_4.4" data="4.4">.</li>
    <li id="neck_4.3" data="4.3">.</li>
    <li id="neck_4.2" data="4.2">.</li>
    <li id="neck_4.1" data="4.1">.</li>
    <li id="neck_4" data="4"><span class="feet_num">4 feet</span> ____</li>
    </ul>
```

" here is my scale i am selecting the li elements from the given value of text field and through that value i need to change background of lis from the current code it only changing the values of those lis whose ids are single i mean id without . ex(4.1...) etc
i want to take those values in loop to"..

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle?